# Java - using Exceptions

Tags: java, javafx, exception

I need to use exception handling to capture incorrect numeric values when adding numbers. I have the code I created but I am not sure how to do this. can someone show me how it is properly done so i know for the future.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test33 extends Application {
    private double num1 = 0, num2 = 0, result = 0;

  @Override
  // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
    pane.setHgap(2);
    TextField tfNumber1 = new TextField();
    TextField tfNumber2 = new TextField();
    TextField tfResult = new TextField();

    tfNumber1.setPrefColumnCount(3);
    tfNumber2.setPrefColumnCount(3);
    tfResult.setPrefColumnCount(3);

    pane.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Number 1: "), tfNumber1,
      new Label("Number 2: "), tfNumber2, new Label("Result: "), tfResult);

    // Create four buttons
    HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
    Button btAdd = new Button("Add");

    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(btAdd);

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(pane);
    borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(hBox, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 375, 150);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test33"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

    btAdd.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(tfNumber1.getText());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(tfNumber2.getText());
            result = num1 + num2;
            tfResult.setText(String.format("%.1f", result)); 
        }
    });



  }

  /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: What constitutes an "incorrect numeric value"? Only it is not a number of some sort (e.g., "asdf" entered in tfNumber1)? Or are there other considerations (e.g., cannot be negative)?

Answer (score 1):

One aspect of the exception handling that should be present is in the `.parseDouble()`. I would suggest adding at a minimum NumberFormatException handling

```
     public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
          num1 = Double.parseDouble(tfNumber1.getText());
          num2 = Double.parseDouble(tfNumber2.getText());
          result = num1 + num2;
          tfResult.setText(String.format("%.1f", result)); 
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
           tfResult.setText("Invalid input!");
        }
    }
```

One can get more fine-grained by catching the specific input that caused the error, etc. However, from a demonstration perspective of catching a bad number, this code is illustrative.